# Read csv/tsv file line by line and split result in Golang

Tags: csv, go, csvreader

I want to read a TSV file in Golang, line by line, and do a process on a column of data.

Here is what my data looks like:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 50 |

Here is a C++ code that works well for my purpose:

```
ifstream iFile("input.tsv");
iFile >> str >> str >> str; // Skip first line
int sum = 0;
while (iFile >> x >> y >> w)
{
    sum += w; // A simple process on the third column.
}
```

But I can't find a similar code for Go.
Here is a code for reading tsv in Goland:

```
file, _ := os.Open("input.tsv")
defer file.Close()
csvReader := csv.NewReader(file)
csvReader.Comma = '\t'
for {
    rec, err := csvReader.Read()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rec[0])
}
```

The result will be:

```
1   2   10
2   3   50
```

But I can't split each record into x, y, w. Each line of output is a string but I prefer a list so I can easily access w. (the third item)

P.S.: The problem is solved. As @JimB showed us [HERE](https://go.dev/play/p/EuM9w0_j0GE), the code is working.

When the tsv file format is correct, the result will be

```
[]string{"1", "2", "10"}
[]string{"2", "3", "50"}
```

but if the tsv file uses multiple spaces instead of a tab, the result will be:

```
[]string{"1   2   100"}
[]string{"2   3   50"}
```

Which is not what we want.

Comment: With error handling added, your code will read tab separated values into a slice for each line: https://go.dev/play/p/EuM9w0_j0GE. Please show a [mre] that replicates your issue

Comment: When handling csv files, I usually have code which checks and corrects (if possible) the formatting before trying to access the parts of the array. I also use the gocsv package quite a bit (https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) as I usually manage the data in struct form rather than a nested array.

Comment: @Jadefox10200 How can I use gocsv to Unmarshal the input file line by line(and not load all data into memory at once)

Comment: @M.Dara I've updated my answer to include a version of how I would use gocsv to read lines. I've never done this in any production code as the largest csv I've needed to read was about 100,000 lines which didn't cause me any issues to marshal the file into an array of structs. My example uses UnmarshalToCallback but you can also use UnmarshalToChan which is possibly safer in terms of error handling.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to load the csv, turn it into a nested array, loop through and access the [2] field on the nested array. I think you're already pretty close, but this is the code I've used:

```
//file path of the master file
f, err := os.Open(filePath)
if err != nil {     
    log.Fatalf("ERROR: error opening file: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()

//pass the file to the reader
r := csv.NewReader(f)   

recs, err := r.ReadAll()
if err != nil {fmt.Printf("Failed to readall: %s\n", err); return}

l := len(recs)

for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
  //Do something with the w field
  w := recs[i][2]
}
```

As mentioned, you can read each line by using a callback in gocsv. I usually don't do this and simply marshal the file and then read but this is how I would do it if I did do it line by line:

```golang
package main

//handlers

import (
    "os"    
    "fmt"   
    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
    
)

func main() {

    file, _ := os.Open("csvTest.csv")
    defer file.Close()

    //CSV READ: 
    err := gocsv.UnmarshalToCallback(file, func(r Job_entry){
        fmt.Println(r.Title)
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

type Job_entry struct {
    //table:                                `csv:""`            // EXAMPLES:
    Job_Id                  int64           `csv:"-"`           // 49914
    Title                   string          `csv:"TITLE"`       // BOOKLET
    Language                string          `csv:"LANGUAGE"`    // ENGLISH
    Quantity                int64           `csv:"QTY"`         // 684
        
}
```

Using a file such as:

```
ID,TITLE,LANGUAGE,QTY
EN.BKLT,Booklet,ENGLISH,400
EN.FORM,A form,ENGLISH,300
JA.BKLT,Booklet,JAPANESE,300
```

However, I usually use gocsv to marshal the file at one time in this manner:

```golang
package main

//handlers

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
    
)

func main() {

    file, _ := os.Open("csvTest.csv")
    defer file.Close()

    //CSV READ:
    csvRecords := []*Job_entry{}
    err := gocsv.Unmarshal(file, &csvRecords)
    if err != nil {fmt.Errorf("There was an error loading the CSV file: %v", err.Error()); return }

    for k, v := range csvRecords {
        fmt.Printf("Rec: %v\t%v\n", k, v.Title)
    }

}

type Job_entry struct {
    //table:                                `csv:""`            // EXAMPLES:
    Job_Id                  int64           `csv:"-"`           // 49914
    Title                   string          `csv:"TITLE"`       // BOOKLET
    Language                string          `csv:"QTY"` // 682
    Quantity                int64           `csv:"LANGUAGE"`            // ENGLISH
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete program that will open the TSV, read it using Go's csv Reader, convert the 3rd column to an int, and accumulate the sum of the ints:

```golang
func main() {
    f, _ := os.Open("input.tsv")
    defer f.Close()

    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    r.Comma = '\t'

    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    records = records[1:] // reslice to omit header

    sum := 0
    for _, record := range records {
        x, err := strconv.Atoi(record[2])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        sum += x
    }

    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

I don't even begin to understand the C++ code, except I can see that the tab char is never specified, so I assume the code works because `>>` means something like "skip to the next thing after a space (which might inlcude a tab)"... I dunno.  To me it looks short, and magical, compared to the Go code.